# Sending mails from localhost in XAMPP with PHP

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost, sendmail

I saw many questions and answers on Stack Overflow and tried many of them to send a mail from localhost in XAMPP, but all the attempts were futile.
Here is my semdmail.ini file:

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=******@gmail.com
auth_password=***
force_sender= *****@gmail.com
```

My php.ini file contains this

```
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
mail.add_x_header = Off
```

My php file is as follows

```
<?php
if(mail ('abcd@gmail.com', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'From: vh@gmail.com'))
{
    echo 'success';
}else
{
    echo 'sorry';
}
?>
```

Though I saw on net, I was unable to find a working solution.

Comment: `sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"` see if that makes a difference. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: No errors are being displayed. and still it's giving the same output. "sorry"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page

Comment: its giving a bunch of errors as      Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Mail\smtp.php on line 365

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Uncomment "extension=php_openssl.dll" in your php.ini (C:\xampp\php\php.ini)
- Uncomment and configure in php.ini the section "[mail function]":

_

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com  
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost

; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesC:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do not work correctly.
; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g. C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.  
; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It writes all mails in the C:\xampp\mailoutput folder
sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

Hope it help

Comment: It is giving success but the mail can't be seen in the inbox or spam. Thanks for the help...(I used my personal email address instead of abcd@gmail.com)